# iOS 5.1 tested app crashing on iOS 4.0

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

My app tested on iOS 5.1 is crashing on ios 4 enabled iPhone.
What could be the possible reasons ?
It appears Apple has stopped supporting older versions now .. the detailed list of changes introduced is not mentioned clearly anywhere..
Any Suggestions or pointers for further debugging ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start will be in the iOS 5 API Differences. This lists everything that has changed between iOS's 4 and 5. Basically, anything on this list that you used in your iOS 5 app that says "added" won't work on iOS 4, just like anything that says "depreciated  " will work in iOS 4 but not 5. Here's the link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html

If you've been over this list and aren't using anything framework added in iOS 5 then you probably have a less obvious problem. If you post your crash log I can be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you used a feature that is unavailable on that version of iOS.  You still have to think about that...just because the code compiled doesn't guarantee it to run on all versions of iOS.  Without any information on the crash though, that's about as specific as anyone can be.

Comment: Thanks.. i wanted an isight from a developer who has developed in iOS 4 and found a new feature in iOS 5.1.. as i started developing in ios 5 only its hard to compare.. thanks for response